# passing a value from service to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I am having difficulty passing the updated value from the global variable URLValue below to the controller. It keeps printing 12345. Any idea?
It seems the updated URLValue does not get passed to the result returned by the function watchingURL which I am not sure why since URLValue is a global variable..

```
 var URLValue = '12345';
 factoryModule = angular.module("factoryDetails" ,[])
.factory( "factoryMain" , ["$sce" ,"$location", "$rootScope", "$q",

    function($sce,$location, $rootScope,$q){
      this.watchingURL = function() { 
        $rootScope.$watch(function () {
          return  $location.path();
        },  
        function (loc) {
          console.log("$location.path() ",$location.path(loc).$$absUrl);
          temp = $location.path(loc).$$absUrl
          URLValue = 789;
        })
        return URLValue;
      };
}]);



app.controller("appController", ["$scope", "factoryMain" 
  function($scope,factoryMain) {
    $scope.name = factoryMain.watchingURL();
    console.log("function passed is" , factoryMain.watchingURL());
    $scope.$watch(factoryMain.watchingURL(), function(newval,oldval){
        $scope.name=newval
        console.log("oldval is ",oldval)
        console.log("newval is ",$scope.name) 
    });
}]);
```

when passing this service to my controller i get URLValue =  12345
any idea?

Comment: First of all, do you really need it to be a global variable? Second, in your controller, why don't you watch for the global variable URLValue instead of trying to get this value from another watch function? This code seems a lit bit confuse. Try these changes and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: hi i actually did not have the watch in the controller before and it was having the same behavior .. I do not want to watch it from the controller because i need it to be inside a service which can distribute it to various controllers so i actually do not want a watch on every controller . that watch in this controller was a desperate move to get the value yet it didn’t work. if you can help using a deferred object please let me know since $watch is asynchronous thanks

Comment: I've created this simply [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9Lyhr4e/7/) to try to help you with my recommended approach. Does this solve your problem? Please let me know.